# Installed ubuntu from rescue

Tags: installation, live-usb

I'm new to ubuntu, 
After extracting the iso file on the usb drive with the software provided by pendrivelinux.com and tried to install it but i got this error (casper/vmlinuz file not found) in the menu.
after that i tried running the "rescue option" and hopefully it worked but the problem is that only shell was install by that there's no GUI :| .
I'm tried searching it on internet but i couldn't find anything.I'm totally confused.
Is there any way out to get the GUI too ?

P.S: I used official ubuntu torrent link to download the iso.

Comment: It sounds like your live-usb did not create properly, so it did not boot into the Ubuntu live environment GUI. Follow the official steps to make a live-usb disk as I answered below.

Comment: ok so i'll have to format the disk again. right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the downloaded ISO is not corrupt by [comparing it's MD5 hash](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows).

Then use the method for [creating a bootable USB with the Ubuntu wiki help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#From_Windows) instead of using Pendrivelinux.

Since you are new to Ubuntu I take it you will do this from Windows. Otherwise scroll through that same wiki page for instructions on creating the usb from Ubuntu/Mac.

Comment: ok!  i'll try that but isn't there any way to fix the current installation ?

Comment: so you did install on to the hard disk from the full installation?

Comment: I suggest you re-create the live-usb with the official steps. boot it and run the FULL setup again. But now, when you choose your partitions, do NOT format your /home, instead tell the partitioner to keep the existing files.

Comment: not full installation just used 'rescue mode', formated the disk and used something like "setup filesystem" as an option.

Comment: Ah okay that is the problem: You have to run the full setup the first time. The rescue mode only works on a full install. Good Luck! :-)